# Excel VBA - Copy non-blank cell value based on separate range values

Tags: excel

I've got a spreadsheet with a couple thousand rows of invoice information, and the data is provided with incomplete purchase order info. I am trying to populate the purchase information based on the invoice, since at least one line for the invoice will include the purchase order number. I would like to use VBA since I plan to use this as part of a larger macro for automatically formatting and updating a report.

Example raw data:

```
+---------+----------------+
| Invoice | Purchase Order |
+---------+----------------+
| 1000    | -              |
+---------+----------------+
| 1000    | 1234           |
+---------+----------------+
| 1000    | 1234           |
+---------+----------------+
| 1000    | -              |
+---------+----------------+
| 2000    | 4321           |
+---------+----------------+
| 2000    | -              |
+---------+----------------+
| 2000    | -              |
+---------+----------------+
| 3000    | -              |
+---------+----------------+
| 3000    | -              |
+---------+----------------+
| 3000    | 9876           |
+---------+----------------+
```

What I'd like to have as an output:

```
+---------+----------------+
| Invoice | Purchase Order |
+---------+----------------+
| 1000    | 1234           |
+---------+----------------+
| 1000    | 1234           |
+---------+----------------+
| 1000    | 1234           |
+---------+----------------+
| 1000    | 1234           |
+---------+----------------+
| 2000    | 4321           |
+---------+----------------+
| 2000    | 4321           |
+---------+----------------+
| 2000    | 4321           |
+---------+----------------+
| 3000    | 9876           |
+---------+----------------+
| 3000    | 9876           |
+---------+----------------+
| 3000    | 9876           |
+---------+----------------+
```

I've searched quite a bit for a solution, but I haven't had much luck identifying something that will suit this need.

Comment: Have you considered Power Query? If you're just generating a report, then it's probably all you would need. No macros either so no security concerns. I'm sure the M language will provide all of the tools you would need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a more advanced way to do this, but here's something that will get you started in the Power Query realm.

Put your data in a table called Table1. Click cell in the table then click `From Table` in the `Get and Transform` area of the ribbon.

When the query editor comes up, enter the following through the Advanced Editor:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Invoice", Int64.Type}, {"Purchase Order", type any}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type",{"Invoice"},Filtered,{"Invoice"},"Table1 (2)",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Table1 (2)" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table1 (2)", {"Purchase Order"}, {"Purchase Order.1"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Table1 (2)",{"Purchase Order"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

With this method you'll need to create a duplicate query so you can merge the data and fill in all of the gaps. Right click the first query and select `Duplicate Query`:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Invoice", Int64.Type}, {"Purchase Order", type any}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Purchase Order] <> "-"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

The end result is a table where all the gaps are filled.

Comment: Instead of just copying the M code above (so you can practice using the editor), I recommend pulling in the table, duplicating the query, filtering the duplicated query to remove the hyphens, then merging the first table with the filtered duplicate using the `Merge Queries` button.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've never used Power Query before, but it looks like it may be able to accomplish what I need.

Comment: You can also automate query creation and query refreshes with VBA. Please remember to mark as answer if this ends up working for you.

Comment: If I get a new batch of data (in the same layout), will I need to create a new "table1" in order for the query to run? I think that's the only spot where there's a gap in my understanding of the Power Query steps.

Comment: Having to create an actual table if you don't need to is annoying, I agree. The way I've avoided that in the past is to simply maintain the dataset in a separate file (an independent Excel workbook, a text file, a csv file, etc) and import it into Power Query using either the `New Query` button in the Get and Transform section or from within the Query Editor itself (don't recall exactly which toolbar section it's in but it's there).

Comment: I should also note that whenever the source file changes (edited, appended to whatever), refreshing the query automatically pulls in those changes.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to accomplish that. The following is without VBA.

**Step 1:** Start by sorting your table by column A (ascending) + column B (ascending). That gets you to this:

[image: after ordering]

**Step 2:** Add a third column with this formula:

`=IF(B2<>"-",B2,C1)`

**Step 3:** Copy it into all rows.

Result:

[image: Result]

**Attention:** The results in column C will mess up if you change the sorting of A and B. If sorting is inevitable, copy & paste values of column C (i.e. remove formulae) before changing the sort order.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm familiar with the process using Excel, but I am trying to use VBA since would be part of a larger automated process.